# Subwoofer volume control slider does nothing

Tags: sound, 18.04, volume-control

In my fresh Ubuntu 18.04 desktop I can't control sub woofer volume! I have connected a 5.1 Sony muteki speaker system through my GeForce 660TI HDMI out and works great, but sub woofer volume is too loud, and if I try to control it through system volume control slider, it does nothing!

[image: Standard Ubuntu 18.04 sub woofer volume control does nothing]

As you can see in the screenshot, there's one sub woofer slider, but moving that does not change sub woofer volume in the speaker system.